# Read JSON using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I read `sub_merchant_name` from this script using MySQL? I tried

```
< 'request_params'->> '$.sub_merchant_name' as "merchant name" >
```

But it's not working.

```
{
  "customer_id": 658748,
  "brand_id": "75435",
  "bill_amount": "1.00",
  "discount_amount": null,
  "net_bill_amount": null,
  "callback_url": "https:\/\/secuwe.pani.in\/80A522021ef76cd501efd5d315fb7b9x\/CommonPgResponseHandler",
  "merchant_transaction_id": "15048566771",
  "hash_webhook_url": null,
  "transaction_webhook_url": null,
  "merchant_transaction_notes": "Playerzpot Deposit",
  "cancellation_allowed_till": "2022-04-22 16:43:30",
  "pg_source": "twid",
  "callback_url_success": null,
  "callback_url_failure": null,
  "integration_channel": "cashmere",
  "sub_merchant_id": "150799",
  "sub_merchant_name": "wwwplayerzpotcom"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  content text
);
INSERT INTO test (content) VALUES ('{
  "customer_id": 658748,
  "brand_id": "75435",
  "bill_amount": "1.00",
  "discount_amount": null,
  "net_bill_amount": null,
  "callback_url": "https:\/\/secuwe.pani.in\/80A522021ef76cd501efd5d315fb7b9x\/CommonPgResponseHandler",
  "merchant_transaction_id": "15048566771",
  "hash_webhook_url": null,
  "transaction_webhook_url": null,
  "merchant_transaction_notes": "Playerzpot Deposit",
  "cancellation_allowed_till": "2022-04-22 16:43:30",
  "pg_source": "twid",
  "callback_url_success": null,
  "callback_url_failure": null,
  "integration_channel": "cashmere",
  "sub_merchant_id": "150799",
  "sub_merchant_name": "wwwplayerzpotcom"
}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT json_extract(content,'$.sub_merchant_name') as sub_merchant_name FROM test;
```

| sub_merchant_name |
| --- |
| "wwwplayerzpotcom" |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2P3M1srQNtYhMiX274AZ9B/0)

Comment: Throwing this error {

SELECT json_extract(request_params,'$.sub_merchant_name') as sub_merchant_name FROM c_external_payment_handover LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1370 - execute command denied to user 'twit_ro_utkardh'@'%' for routine 'twiddb.json_extract' }

Comment: @ust what is your schema and query look like, show it on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: My table name is c_external_payment_handover and column is request_params.

Comment: @ust how come you got error message, just change table name and column name. You can see my db-fiddle it works well in MySQL v8.0. You must miss someting